# How to stop showing error in Visual studio 2010 for javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I see every time error in my visual studio even code working fine for me in every browser.

the problem is that i not want to watch the error window every time

"`Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method`"

how i can stop visual studio to showing errors relate to my javascript code.

Comment: What is the error with reference to?

Comment: why i should. my function try to call three or four function some of them not implemented in all browser. this is not error but they give me error. well how i can stop this if i want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment:

> my function try to call
>   three or four function some of them
>   not implemented in all browser. this
>   is not error but they give me error.
>   well how i can stop this if i want to

Usually you test first whether the function is implemented - for example, if you'd like to use `getElementsByClassName`:

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName){
    var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('myclass');
    ...
}
```

The condition in the first line returns only true if the function actually exists.

**EDIT:**

As to Visual Studio 2010, it seems that activating debugging for silverlight turns off debugging for javascript, see http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/06/disabling-script-debugging-with-vs-2010.html

I usually use Firefox instead of IE and therefore never had that particular problem.

Comment: i thing we both going wrong. first is that i thing that i am unclear. well i use jQuery plugin so they are work fine for me and i test it in every browser and they work fine for me. well that's not error because they have another option if one of them not work. well this is not my question how javascript... i just need to stop the error window in visual studio who disturb me from a time.

Comment: Error window when you compile? Or when you debug (F5)?